# Learning Management System using php codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

Is there any open source Learning Management Softwares that is developed using codeigniter?

a Web based software for delivering,tracking and managing training/education that focuses mainly on Class/session scheduling, Class enrollment/registration, Teachers/Trainers,Students and Lessons/Courses/Categories/Evaluation

I'm a BSIT student currently doing my thesis.. which is, to create a Learning Management System but unfortunately I'm running out of time.. and I'm planing to use software to develop it fast... I'm a newbie studying codeigniter and I guess I cant make all of this from scratch.

Comment: I think you need to define what a "Learning management software" is exactly and what it's supposed to do.

Comment: a Web based software for delivering,tracking and managing training/education

that focuses mainly on Class/session scheduling, Class enrollment/registration, Teachers/Trainers,Students and Lessons/Courses/Categories/Evaluation

Comment: codeigniter will help you build your app more quickly but it sounds like you probably have quite bespoke requirements. More to the point, it sounds like you're hoping someone has already done the practical part of your thesis for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at this page of the codeigniter wiki. http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Applications_Using_Code_Igniter/.

There are many examples of projects which use codeigniter, many of the applications are open source; however, what you need is non-API specific.

You need to define the data requirements for your system and design a database, if you are struggling with this here is a head-start http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/e_learning/index.htm.

You will find most of the database help you will ever need on that website.

Once you have basic in-roads into the database start writing code, http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/, will answer most of your questions about codeigniter.